# Textarea does not get serialized in my file, but works in jsFiddle

Tags: jquery, html, serialization

I have a wery strange problem I cant figure out, I have this code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8aq0n5h/). Works like a charm in jsFiddle, but *not* in my project (the code has been copied and pasted from my live webpage).

My problem is simply that content from my TextArea doesn't get serialized...

The return from my project is `kid=227&type=0&msg=`, while the jsFiddle returns the correct data: `kid=957&type=0&msg=asdfasdf`

I have seen wery many post related to this, but none that could help or explain what could be going on... Does any of you have a idea?

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="sendMessage" method="post" action="index2.php?page=Innboks&amp;action=sendMelding">
    <input type="hidden" name="kid" value="957">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="0">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon btn btnStandardmelding" onclick="$(this).MessageWiz(this.nextSibling)">
            Standardmelding <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
        </span>
        <textarea id="TEXT_957" name="msg" class="form-control custom-control" rows="2" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
        <span onclick="$('#sendMessage').submit()" class="input-group-addon btn">Send</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this javascript:

```
function ajaxForm(id) {
    var frm = jQuery(id);
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        var data = frm.serialize();
        alert(data);
        ev.preventDefault();
        //return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
}

ajaxForm("#sendMessage");
```

Best regards, Richard

### Edit

So I guess my onClick function called submit on the wrong form... my updated code uses `$(this).parents('form').submit()` and submits the correct form, but my ajaxForm override dosn't activate, and I get redirected to my json results... 
Also tried `$(this).parents('form').trigger('submit')` with the same results.

Even overriding my submit() function does not work! `frm.submit= function (ev) {`

Comment: If the plain example works and it does not work in your project, then you have some code which changes the behavior from expected to unexpected. I would debug my Javascript and the example Javascript if I were you until I find the first relevant differences.

Comment: Usually because fiddle wraps your code in a load handler by default, you probably haven't done that in your file ..`$(function(){ ajaxForm("#sendMessage");});`

Comment: Thanks for your attention... I just dont know how to debug that properly, As far as I can tell, the only thing that gets activated when that form submits, is the `ajaxForm`code...

Comment: @charlietfl , I have a script under all my messages that activates my ajaxForm functionality... (also I do get a respons from ajaxForm when I press my button, so thats not the issue)

Comment: I was wondering if it's got something to do with this `id="TEXT_957" name="msg"`. Can you try and change the value of `id` attribute to `msg`?

Comment: I have, without any look... But I have found 1 issue :P `onclick="$('#sendMessage').submit()"` probably submits the wrong form :O (I have about 20 forms...) I have tried with `$(this.form).submit()` but then ajaxForm didnt get triggered at all...

Comment: updated to `this.form.submit()` but the only respons I got then was: `Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined`